# cant download file using drpbox API v2 python

Tags: python-2.7, dropbox-api

Im trying to download file using the API v2 of dropbox
this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import sys

import dropbox
from dropbox.files import WriteMode
from dropbox.exceptions import ApiError, AuthError

TOKEN = '{TOKEN}'



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Check for an access token
    if len(TOKEN) == 0:
        sys.exit("ERROR: Looks like you didn't add your access token. ")

    # Create an instance of a Dropbox class, which can make requests to the API.
    print("Creating a Dropbox object...")

    with dropbox.Dropbox(TOKEN) as dbx:
        try:
            md, res = dbx.files_download(path='/test/dropbox_test.txt')
        except dropbox.exceptions.HttpError as err:
            print('*** HTTP error', err)
    print("Done!")
```

but I'm getting error

```
BadInputError('1c38b505bb634f5985ef65e745c153f1', 'Error in call to API function "files/download": Your app is not permitted to access this endpoint because it does not have the required scope \'files.content.read\'. The owner of the app can enable the scope for the app using the Permissions tab on the App Console.')
```

I don't understand this error and how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox now uses "scopes" to configure what functionality an app can access. For example, to use [the `files_download` method](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_download), which calls [the /2/files/download endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download), the app needs the `files.content.read` scopes. You can find more information about scopes on Dropbox in [the Dropbox OAuth Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide).

You can enable scopes for your app via "Permissions" tab of the app's page on [the App Console](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps).

Note that this does not retroactively affect existing access tokens, so you'll need to get a new access token once that scope is enabled.